# Maven & JaCoCo - How do exclude a class from the report that's brought in from a dependency?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I'm adding JaCoCo to a project and i'm struggling to have it exclude a class (that's been brought in via a dependency) from the report for a submodule. This is the error i'm getting:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site (default-site):
Error generating jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:report:
Error while creating report:
Error while analyzing ~/proj/submod/target/classes/mydep-jar-with-dependencies.jar@com/jlb/proj/pkg/MyClass.class. Can't add different class with same name: com/jlb/proj/pkg/MyClass
```

And the jar in question is brought into the submodule like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.jlb.pkg</groupId>
    <artifactId>mydep</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The jacoco reports are generated via a  block in the project's overall parent POM, however i've added an override into the submodule in question here, that should exclude the class (the version of the class from the dependency) its complaining about, but it's having no effect:

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>report</report>
              <report>report-integration</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/com/jlb/proj/pkg/MyClass.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

So how do I exclude the offending class from the report?

Answer (score 0):

Please try where `com.jlb.pkg` should be your base package
tie the jacoco report generation with your test phase of your maven build

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com/jlb/pkg/**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: no this still has no effect. If it's the report goal it's complaining about, Should I add this in the report block?

Comment: OK, so that works. I'm generating seperate unit & integration reports. If I add the include to the report goal configuration, that fixes it. However how do I do this when i've defined the reports in the <reporting> section, so they get executed with mvn site?

Answer (score 0):

So, it was specifically in the jacoco exec for the integration tests where the conflict was occuring, but in the reporting section, i've added the include there, that should exclude any classes coming in from JARs:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>com/jlb/**/*.class</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>report</report>
              <report>report-integration</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```